# How to uninstall GRUB bootloader without starting OS?

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader, 17.10

I have recently uninstalled Ubuntu 17.10 by formatting the partition and when I rebooted I got a message saying:
error: no such partition
entering rescue mode...
grub rescue >
No commands worked
So I am wondering, is there a way to uninstall the bootloader so I can boot back into Windows?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/949219/how-to-fix-the-windows-10-boot-loader-from-windows/1021657 - basically boot windows (from installation media) and reinstall windows' boot sector.

Comment: Have you tried changing the Boot Order in the CMOS yet? I'm wondering since you said "Formatted the Partition" Which partition did you format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) (answers have instructions for repairing the Windows bootloader without reinstalling Windows)

Comment: Don't have install media or the possibility to make any at the moment

Comment: I will in 10-20 minutes

Answer (score 2):

Make a live usb with ubuntu 17.10 
and insert following commands to remove grub error

```
sudo apt-get install lilo
sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr
```

It always have worked for me

Comment: If OP can't boot to anything this is not possible.

Comment: Well I'm going to make a install media soon when I have the possibility